# How do the readers fields should work like?

Tags: couchdb

In release notes of CouchDB 0.11 is stated, that it supports readers fields. I guess it should work similary as in Lotus Notes.  But unfortunately I cant find any documentation on this topic. Can someone point me to documentation or some brief explanation at least?

Thank you
David

Comment: Hi, David. I am not sure I understand you. Do you mean the CHANGES file which says "Added per-database reader access control lists" ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a good introduction in [the Couchbase blog](http://blog.couchbase.com/whats-new-in-couchdb-1-0-part-4-securityn-stuff). Slightly confusingly, a "reader" can also write to the database, but that can be curtailed by use of the `validate_doc_update` document.